# Send GET request to Plone form built with zope.formlib

Tags: python, plone

I've a form built with zope.formlib. When I fill the form and push submit, I can see the result in the browser. Now, I would like to reference these results from other places so the results would be avaible for the users without filling the form.
I've tried to built an URL adding the parameters after the form URL to do a GET request like this: @@page?param1=myparam1&param2=myparam2

This way I can't get the result to get load. It only shows the form.

Is there something missing? Does zope.formlib allow GET requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zope.formlib` applies actions based on the presence of the action name in the request; usually this is done by giving the submit button the name of the action.

By including that name in your GET request you thus invoke the action. Note that actions are prefixed by both the form identifier and the 'action' keyword, so the `save` action will generally be using the parameter name `form.action.save`:

@@page?param1=myparam1&param2=myparam2&form.action.save=Save

Easiest way to discover the exact name of your action parameters is to just look at the output generated for your form and look for the `.action.` names.